# Using Regex within Nginx sub_filter

Tags: regex, nginx

I am trying to delete the content of specific attribute within the HTML content while using `sub_filter` modul in nginx proxy.

This is an example of the attribute that I am trying to delete its content:

```
integrity="sha256-JcCQTfQJfXQCI9Pgu4C8DsPBm7t6k/3SvAXTFPsXuBk= sha512-l4H3xn9koLbrXcevxo6Hs0TnepFHVLGgQM9tUMgsYxLDsyfVzWen1sqgozMDp1hh7dF1aR3bhNTp+jjrEBTIIA=="
```

So far I've tried different variation of regular expresions which should work but actually don't work in nginx, for example this one:

`sub_filter integrity=".*?" integrity="";`

Is my approach wrong? How can I achieve this task in nginx?

Comment: I don't know Nginx but your regex pattern seems valid to me. Alternatively, you could try `integrity="[^"]*"`.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be [`subs_filter`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/substitutions/) instead of `sub_filter`?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed `subs_filter` is an external modul, I will give it a try later.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not wrong, but the regex pattern you are using is not valid for the sub_filter module in nginx.  sub_filter  uses  PCRE regex syntax, and the pattern integrity=".*?" is not a valid PCRE one.

its content would be:

integrity="(?.*?)=(?.*?)"

This pattern will match the entire integrity attribute, including the name, the value of the sha256 checksum, and the value of the sha512 checksum.

The (?.*?) and (?.*?) capture groups will capture the values of the sha256 and sha512 checksums

The sub_filter directive can then be used to replace the entire integrity attribute with an empty string:

sub_filter integrity="(?.*?)=(?.*?)" "";
This will effectively delete the integrity attribute from the HTML content.

eg:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    sub_filter integrity="(?<sha256>.*?)=(?<sha512>.*?)" "";
  }
}
```

This will proxy all requests to the server at localhost:8080.